# Oracle order by in select depends on parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have pipelined function that return table, it looks like there:

```
type transactions is record (
  trans_date date,
  terminal varchar2(20)
);
type transactions_rec_list is table of transactions;

function get_transactions_by_card (
  in_idcard in number,
  in_datefrom in date,
  in_dateto in date,
  in_order_by_id in varchar2
)
return transactions_rec_list parallel_enable pipelined is
begin
  for trns in (
    select   
      t.trans_date,
      t.terminal
    from transactions t
    where t.idcard = in_idcard 
      and t.date >= in_datefrom
      and t.date <= in_dateto
    order by trans_date desc
  )
  loop pipe row (trns);
  end loop;
end;
```

How to do to choose `order by` `desc` or `asc` will depends on what value of parameter `in_order_by_id` there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select   
  t.trans_date,
  t.terminal
from transactions t
where t.idcard = in_idcard 
  and t.date >= in_datefrom
  and t.date <= in_dateto
order by 
  case when in_order_by_id = 'desc' then trans_date end desc,
  case when in_order_by_id = 'asc' then trans_date end asc
```